# Linq group objects by unique values and make two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of objects with property Number inside them. I need to group them by values i.e. objects contain those sample values:

```
1 2 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 6 7 7
```

I have to group them like this:

```
listOfUniqe = {1,2,4,5}
listOfDuplicates1 = {3,3,3}
listOfDuplicates2 = {6,6,6}
listOfDuplicates3 = {7,7}
...
```

I tried to use distinct, with `First()`. But this distincts me first occurences and remove duplicates. I want to erase also first occurence of object if it had duplicates and move them to another list.

```
List<Reports> distinct = new List<Reports>;
distinct = ArrayOfObjects.GroupBy(p => p.Number).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get groups with just one element use that:

```
distinct = ArrayOfObjects.GroupBy(p => p.Number)
                         .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                         .ToList();
```

And to get list of groups with more elements use that:

```
nonDistinct = ArrayOfObjects.GroupBy(p => p.Number)
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                            .Select(g => g.ToList())
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

First group the items:

```
var groups = values.GroupBy(p => p.Number).ToList();
```

The unique ones are the ones with a group count of one:

```
var unique = groups.Where(g => g.Count() == 1).Select(g => g.Single()).ToList();
```

The ones with duplicates are the other ones:

```
var nonUnique = groups.Where(g => g.Count() > 1).ToList();
```